# Use jsp include tag with "<%= ..." expression

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, jsp-tags

Why is it not possible to combine a jsp include tag with an `<%= ... %>` expression?

```
<jsp:include page="pages/<%= element.convertToLowercase() %>.jsp"></jsp:include>
```

The `element.convertToLowercase()` returns the page that should be displayed.

Instead I'm getting the error `Failed to decode [/pages/<%= element.convertToLowercase() %>.jsp] because the % character must be followed by two hexademical digits`.

My suspicion is that the `<%=` expression is being red as part of the URL and not as an jsp expression.

How can this be implemented instead?

Full stacktrace:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to decode [/pages/<%= element.convertToLowercase() %>.jsp] because the % character must be followed by two hexademical digits
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.UDecoder.URLDecode(UDecoder.java:431)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.getRequestDispatcher(ApplicationContext.java:429)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContextFacade.getRequestDispatcher(ApplicationContextFacade.java:227)
> at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getRequestDispatcher(Request.java:1417)
> at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getRequestDispatcher(RequestFacade.java:614)
> at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:952)
> at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:285)
> at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:71)
> at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
> at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:467)
> at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:378)
> at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:326)
> at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
> at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
> at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)
> at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
> at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:687)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
> at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
> at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374)
> at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
> at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1707)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)

Comment: can't you use expression language page="pages/${element.convertToLowercase()}>.jsp"?

Comment: Please try using <% String elementPage = "pages/" + element.convertToLowercase() + ".jsp";%>
<jsp:include page="<%=elementPage%>"></jsp:include>

Comment: @Kaneda I can't. The expression language is being ignored. The output string is `pages/.jsp`

Comment: @rickz Thanks, this is similar to my workaround using a function that returns the entire string, but shouldn't be the actual goal.

Answer (score 0):

Your suspicion is right. You can simply build the url in a scriptlet tag before the include action.